# PHP (PDO) file to send mail with multiple query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, email, pdo

i have this php code using which i want to send email to the user. Once the mail is sent, a pop-up will specify that the mail has been sent. However, as I type the basic structure of the mail body, i am getting error when i try to include the information in a table. below are the codes and the error:

PHP (to send email) (sendmail.php)

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 

$form=$_POST;
$accountnumber=$form['accountnumber'];
$trade=$form['tradetype'];
$metal=$form['metal'];
$amount=$form['amount'];
$date=$form['date'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerCode='$accountnumber'"); 
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contracts WHERE Trade='$trade' AND Metal='$metal' AND Amount='$amount' AND ExpiryDate='$date'");
  while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

 $to= $row['Email'];
 $subject= "Bullion Assets Management_Trade Order Confirmation - <?php print strftime('%d %B %Y');?>
 $body = "<table>;
 $body .="<tr>";
 $body .="<td>"Dear $row['Name']; "</td>"
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="<tr>";
 $body .="<td>"Fixed Minimum $trade Price Pre-Order Confirmation"</td>";
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="<tr>";
 $body .="<td>"1) Bullion Assets Management Pte Ltd confirms receipt and accepts your pre-order to $trade $amount of 9999 Pooled Allocated $metal Loco Singapore (“$metal”) on $date London PM Fix at minimum fixed price at USD or higher."</td>";
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="<tr>";
 $body .="<td>"2) This pre-order will enable a discount of USD $row1['DiscountPremium']; per oz ( notional value USD $row1[DiscountPremium'];*$amount ) upon your $metal purchase."</td>";
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="<tr>";
 $body .="<td>"3) <<IMPORTANT>> - If the PM FIX on the above date is below USD $row1['Price']; per troy oz, you will still be obligated to buy at the minimum price of USD  $row1['Price']; per troy oz."</td>";
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="<tr>";
       if(isset($trade='Buy') {
 $body .="<td>"4) A deposit of SGD 5000 will be required for your pre-order. This deposit will be used to offset the purchase amount upon your $metal purchase."</td>";
       } else {
 $body .="<td>"4) No deposit is required for your pre-order."</td>";
       }
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="<tr>";
 $body .="<td>"5) The pre-order minimum buying price and discount cannot be changed or cancelled upon signed confirmation of this order. You can however submit a new selling order at the PM Fix if you do not wish to proceed with your $metal purchase and collection."</td>";
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="<tr>";
 $body .="<td>"6) Settlement and/or collection of $metal from Bullion Assets Management Pte Ltd is to be completed within 2 business days from $date."</td>";
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="<tr>";
 $body .="<td>"This acknowledgement by you is subject to and constitutes a supplement to the Customer Agreement signed between you and Bullion Assets Management Pte Ltd."</td>";
 $body .="</tr>";
 $body .="</table>";
});
});
$conn-->close();

        $headers = From: "ashwini@goldsilvercentral.com.sg";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n';
        $headers .= 'X-Priority: 1\r\n';
        $headers .= 'X-MSMail-Priority: High\n';
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n';

       mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers );
       echo "Your Order has been submitted";
 }     
?>
```

Jquery for the above php file

```
 $('#confirm_btn').click(function() {

    var accountnumber = $('#accountnumber').val();
    var tradetype = $('input.tradetype:checked').val();
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var metal = $('input.metal:checked').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
      url: "sendorder.php", /* THE FILE WHERE YOU PROCESS THE SELECT QUERY */
      data: {"accountnumber": accountnumber, "tradetype": tradetype, "amount": amount, "metal": metal, "date":  date}, /* THE DATA WE WILL SUBMIT TO retrievepremordisc.php */
      success: function(data){ 
              successmessage = 'sucess';
      }
    });
  });
```

So the error i get is for the php file: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in on line 20 ( $body = ";)

any suggestions as to the error?

also, how do i get the pop-up to appear? thank you in advance!

Comment: As the error states, you have a syntax error on line 20, specifically you are missing the closing quote. Change `$body = "<table>;` to `$body = "<table>";`

Comment: Actually, you have a bunch of syntax errors in there, hold on

Comment: @DelightedD0D i get the same error with or without the "

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of errors in your code, mostly related to the way you are trying to concatenate your strings but also with how you are accessing variables and terminating your while loops. Here is your code cleaned up a bit. I cant test it on my end to make sure this will work as expected but it should at least get you on the right path.

### PHP

```
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);


$accountnumber = isset($_POST['accountnumber']) ? $_POST['accountnumber'] : NULL;
$trade = isset($_POST['tradetype']) ? $_POST['tradetype'] : NULL;
$metal = isset($_POST['metal']) ? $_POST['metal'] : NULL;
$amount = isset($_POST['amount']) ? $_POST['amount'] : NULL;
$date = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : NULL;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerCode='$accountnumber'");
$failedEmails=0;
$sentEmails=0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contracts WHERE Trade='$trade' AND Metal='$metal' AND Amount='$amount' AND ExpiryDate='$date'");
    while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $to = $row['Email']; // what are you trying to do here? are you attempting to send the email to serevral addresses at once?
        $subject = 'Bullion Assets Management_Trade Order Confirmation -' . strftime('%d %B %Y');

        if (isset($trade) && $trade == 'Buy') {
            $deposit = '<td>4) A deposit of SGD 5000 will be required for your pre-order. This deposit will be used to offset the purchase amount upon your $metal purchase.</td>';
        } else {
            $deposit = '<td>4) No deposit is required for your pre-order.</td>';
        }
        $body = '<table>' .
            '<tr><td>Dear' . $row['Name'] . '</td></tr>' .
            '<tr><td>Fixed Minimum ' . $trade . ' Price Pre-Order Confirmation</td></tr>' .
            '<tr><td>1) Bullion Assets Management Pte Ltd confirms receipt and accepts your pre-order to $trade $amount of 9999 Pooled Allocated $metal Loco Singapore ("' . $metal . '") on $date London PM Fix at minimum fixed price at USD or higher.</td></tr>' .
            '<tr><td>2) This pre-order will enable a discount of USD ' . $row1['DiscountPremium'] . ' per oz ( notional value USD ' . $row1['DiscountPremium'] * $amount . ') upon your $metal purchase.</td></tr>' .
            '<tr><td>3) &lt;&lt;IMPORTANT&gt;&gt; - If the PM FIX on the above date is below USD ' . $row1['Price'] . ' per troy oz, you will still be obligated to buy at the minimum price of USD ' . $row1['Price'] . '  per troy oz.</td></tr>' .
            '<tr>' . $deposit . '</tr>' .
            '<tr><td>5) The pre-order minimum buying price and discount cannot be changed or cancelled upon signed confirmation of this order. You can however submit a new selling order at the PM Fix if you do not wish to proceed with your $metal purchase and collection.</td></tr>' .
            '<tr><td>"6) Settlement and/or collection of $metal from Bullion Assets Management Pte Ltd is to be completed within 2 business days from $date.</td></tr>' .
            '<tr><td>This acknowledgement by you is subject to and constitutes a supplement to the Customer Agreement signed between you and Bullion Assets Management Pte Ltd.</td></tr>' .
            '</table>';

        $headers = 'From: ashwini@goldsilvercentral.com.sg';
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n';
        $headers .= 'X-Priority: 1\r\n';
        $headers .= 'X-MSMail-Priority: High\n';
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n';

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ? $sentEmails++ : $failedEmails++;
    }
}


if ($failedEmails==0) echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Your Order has been submitted']);
else echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'There was a problem submitting your order. Only '.$sentEmails.' of '.($sentEmails+$failedEmails).' emails were sent.']);
$conn-- > close();
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#confirm_btn').click(function () {
    var accountnumber = $('#accountnumber').val();
    var tradetype = $('input.tradetype:checked').val();
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var metal = $('input.metal:checked').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "sendorder.php", /* THE FILE WHERE YOU PROCESS THE SELECT QUERY */
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "accountnumber": accountnumber,
            "tradetype": tradetype,
            "amount": amount,
            "metal": metal,
            "date": date
        }, /* THE DATA WE WILL SUBMIT TO retrievepremordisc.php */
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.success='true'){
                alert(data.message);
                // order was submitted
            }
            else{
                alert(data.message);
                // order was NOT submitted
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the $to part, i am trying to send to the email address from my database which matches an accountnumber as mentioned in the query $stmt. also, what i am trying to do is that from the query, the results are to be displayed in the email body at different places rather than together in one place... i have been trying to find a way to do it but havent found it so wrote this code after editing on one which has worked before...

Comment: Please see my edits, I cant test it on my end but that should get it

Comment: i am getting the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in "" on line 23 ( '<tr><td>Dear ' . $row['Name'] . '</td></tr>' . )

Comment: what does `var_dump($row['Name'])` return?

Comment: The code for the table works without the variables, see http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7h9h-ff5j, so I'd look at the variables as the cause. `var_dump($row['Name'])` should print out the variable, you're saying it doesnt do that?

Comment: Yes unfortunately its the variables issue